# installing visualsvn on an active win2003 web server

Tags: iis-6, visualsvn-server

We need to install a Subversion server on one of our production web servers.  I know this is not best practice but we have a distributed team of developers so we need it accessible to them and our web-facing server options are limited.  Anyway, what is the correct method for installing VisualSVN on an active Win 2003 server?  When I started the install it wanted to use ports 443 and 80 so I stopped the installer.  Our existing sites are already configured for the HTTP ports.  How can I install VisualSVN and not clobber our current sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**  I installed it using port 8080 and skipped SSL since we dont require it anyway.  It works great alongside the other sites.